# C# Return true if string is different from any of the string in a list of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

How do I achieve the same result as code below using LINQ?

What it do is if a string is different from any of the string in a list of strings, it will return true.

```
public static bool MasterPlantDifferentFromDetailPlant(string mrNumber)
{
    string masterPlant = t_MT_MTInfo.GetMaterialRequestPlant(mrNumber);
    List<string> detailPlants = t_MT_MTItem.GetPlants(mrNumber);
    bool differentPlant = false; 
    foreach (string plant in detailPlants)
    {
        if (string.Compare(masterPlant.Trim(), plant.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
        {
            differentPlant = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return differentPlant;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by why you want to do this. Surely if there is more than one item in the list then *any* string will be not equal to one of them.  That is, you have a list "tulip", "rose", "plum" and you search for "rose", and it says, yes, "tulip" is different than "rose".  Surely you want the opposite: you want to know if the string is different from *every* member on the list, not *any* member of the list, right?

Comment: @EricLippert To the system, if master is "rose", then details should be list of "rose" only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
detailPlants.Any(p => string.Compare(masterPlant.Trim(), p.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
    public static bool MasterPlantDifferentFromDetailPlant(string mrNumber)
    {
        string masterPlant = t_MT_MTInfo.GetMaterialRequestPlant(mrNumber);
        List<string> detailPlants = t_MT_MTItem.GetPlants(mrNumber);
        return !detailPlants.All(x => string.Equals(masterPlant.Trim(), x.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```